# Loop while não funciona bem - Hakerrank

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando resolver o problema da repeated string do Hackerrank, onde devemos construir uma função que conte o número de letras a repetidas em uma string limitada por um número n.
As entradas da função são n (número limitador) e s, que é a string base.
Vamos supor que s = 'abc'. Se n = 10, então devo contar o número de letras a na string 'abcabcabca'.
Fiz a seguinte função e não consigo entender porque o while não está funcionando:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    lista = list(s)
    listaextra = []
    a = 0
    i = 3
    while i in (len(s), n-len(s)):
        listaextra.append(lista[i%len(s)])
        i += 1
        
    listafinal = lista + listaextra
    for x in range(len(listafinal)):
        if listafinal[x] == 'a':
            a+=1
    return a, i, lista, listaextra, len(s), n-len(s)
```

Ela no final me dá esse retorno: (3, 4, ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a'], 3, 7)
Para esse input: n = 10, s = 'aba'

Alguém sabe me dizer o problema desse código?

Comment: `while i in (len(s), n-len(s))`, consegue nos explicar o que esperava que essa expressão fizesse?

Comment: sim, esperava que ela marcasse um intervalo que começasse depois da última letra de s até chegar em n pra ir adicionando a quantidade de letras certa

Answer (score 2):

> Alguém sabe me dizer o problema desse código?

Sim, eu digo que o código está todo errado. Pelos seguintes motivos:

- A abordagem é complicada demais para um problema simples.
- Não resolve nem o seu problema inicial que é construir uma string com base em outra para contar os caracteres `a` repetidos.
- É de difícil interpretação.
- Mesmo o código fosse corrigido o algoritmo possuiria performance pífia.

Se você tem uma string `s` e quer repeti-la até `n` caracteres a melhor abordagem é dividir o comprimento de `s` por `n` para saber quantas vezes `s` deverá ser repetida e com o resto da divisão pegar uma fração de `s` que completará os caracteres faltantes. Python oferece a função embutida [`divmode()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#divmod) que em uma operação devolve o quociente e o resto de uma divisão:

```
>>>s = 'abc'
>>>n = 10
>>>dm = divmod(n, len(s))
>>>print(s * dm[0] + s[:dm[1]])
abcabcabca
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/vTLYfy)</sup>

Onde:

- `s * dm[0]` é a string `s` repetida pelo quociente `dm[0]`.
- `s[:dm[1]]` é a fração da string `s` determinada pelo resto `dm[1]`.

Então, ou você pode de contar quantas vezes o caractere `a` se repete na string resultante com o auxilio do método [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>>s = 'abc'
>>>n = 10
>>>dm = divmod(n, len(s))
>>>res = s * dm[0] + s[:dm[1]]
>>>print(res.count("a"))
4
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/UyQ5qS)</sup>
Essa solução possui a desvantagem do consumo de memória no caso de `n` ser muito grande, exemplo `n = 1000000000`, com complexidade de tempo multilinear  *O(len(s)*n)*.

Caso queira desempenho, ao invés de contar quantas vezes o caractere `a` se repete na string resultante você pode contar uma vez quantas vezes a letra `a` aparece na string `s` multiplicar pelo quociente e contar outra vez quantas vezes a letra `a` aparece fração da string `s`:

```
>>>s = 'abc'
>>>n = 10
>>>dm = divmod(n, len(s))
>>>c1 = s.count("a") * dm[0]
>>>c2 = s[:dm[1]].count("a")
>>>print(c1 + c2)
4
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/A4TuSC)</sup>
Já essa solução já possui complexidade de tempo constante *O(1)* e trabalha bem com valores absurdos para `n` e `s`.

Empacotando a solução como uma função:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
  dm = divmod(n, len(s))
  c1 = s.count("a") * dm[0]
  c2 = s[:dm[1]].count("a")
  return c1 + c2

print(repeatedString('abc',11234567890987654321))  #3744855963662551441
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/6bugVL)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Olá...

- Primeiro o seu `return` está retornando uma `tupla` com todos os valores que você pediu para serem retornados, isto acontece pois: o python não permite múltiplos retornos, então ele joga tudo isto dentro de uma `tupla` e lhe retorna. Por isto este retorno gigante da função `repeatedString`.
- Segundo o seu código possui alguns erros de lógica e ele está muito mais complexo do que precisa estar. Por exemplo: o valor sendo contando na variável `a` não está certo, a criação de 3 listas diferentes é desnecessária em minha opinião, eu resolvi o exercício com 2 listas. Mas com uma quantidade maior de laços de repetição.
- Gostaria de dizer também que eu não entendi exatamente o seu `while i in (len(s), n-len(s))`. Fiquei um pouco confuso nesta parte. Por isto acho que não consigo explicar o porque o seu laço `while` não dá certo. Todavia segue abaixo a minha resolução do exercício. Qualquer dúvida é só falar!

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    #len de lista tem que ser igual a N
    base = ['0'] * n #lista com tamanho que a lista final devera ficar
    lista_final = []
    cont = 0 #contador
    a = 0 #quantida de 'a'
    while cont < len(base):
        for valores in s: #quebra a string em 's' e caracteres. Ex: "a", "b", "c"
            cont += 1 #soma 1 em cont
            if cont > len(base): #se cont for maior que o tamanho da lista base ignora e deixa o programa voltar ao while que dara False
                pass
            else:
                lista_final.append(valores) #adiciona valores em lista_final
    for x in range(len(lista_final)):
        if lista_final[x] == 'a': #verifica se em lista_final na posicao x existe a letra a
            a += 1 #se o if for True adiciona +1 na variavel a
    
    return a #retorna o valor da variavel a

string = input()
numero = int(input()) 
funcao = repeatedString(string, numero)
print(funcao) #printa o retorno da funcao repeatedString
```